# How to turn a motor while obtaining the angle it turned?

Tags: dc-motor, potentiometer, device

I need a device where it can turn mechanically, while be able to measure the angle of which the motor turned. 
One solution I thought about was to connect the motor with potentiometer.

However, is there any devices that could do the similar job? It's a control circuit, so it doesn't need to turn fast.

Comment: why do you not mention any specs? Like torque, RPM, Hp , watts, shaft diam. Angle resolution , accuracy? Stepper Motors are an obvious choice with 200 steps/ and up to 64 micro-steps if you can tolerate reduced torque.

Comment: Yes there are. A resolver is one such device. There are others.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder

Answer (score 3):

For the most accurate measurement of the angle, it's common to use some kind of encoder on the shaft.

A potentiometer can be used but will likely not be as precise or accurate, and might have a "dead zone" of a few degrees where it can't measure.

Another option, depending on the load and accuracy and precision needed is to use a stepper motor and simply count the number of steps or microsteps you drive it with.